# MongoDb and Storing Relationships Between Objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I am currently planning the development of an application using Node and I am stuck as to whether or not I should use MongoDb as a databse.  Ideally I would like to use it. I understand how it works in general, but what I don't understand is how to reference other objects within a document model.

For example, let's say I have two objects; a User and an Order object.

```
{
    Order : {
        Id: 1,
        Amount: 23.95
        }
}

{
    User: {
        Id: 1,
        Orders: [ ]
        }
}
```

Essentially, a User will place an order, and upon creation of that Order object, I would like for the User object to update the Orders array appropriately.

First of all, I hear alot about MongoDb lacking relational functionality.  So would I be able to store a reference to that order in the Orders array, perhaps by ID? Or should I just store a duplicate of the order object into the array?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would have a field named `userId` in `Order` to keep a reference to the user creating the order. Because the relation between `User` and `Order` is one-to-many, `User` may have many `Order` but `Order` only have one `User`.